# Background only showing after minimized and opened back window in java swing

Tags: java, swing

My code works but the background only shows after I minimize and click back on the java app in the taskbar. I am using Visual Studio

```
import javax.swing.\*;
import javax.swing.plaf.DesktopPaneUI;

import java.awt.\*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class App {
private static ImageIcon shitdowsWallpaper;
public void initialize() {
JFrame desktopFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel desktopPanel = new JPanel();

        desktopFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        desktopFrame.setTitle("shitdows");
        desktopFrame.setSize(1280, 720);
        desktopFrame.setResizable(false);
        desktopFrame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src\\windows_default_wallpaper.png"));
        desktopFrame.add(background);
    }
        
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        App myFrame = new App();
        myFrame.initialize();
    }

}
```

I want the background to show instantly without doing anything extra.

Comment: Have you tried `repaint()`/`revalidate()`?

Comment: There’s nothing unusual about adding a JLabel to a frame hierarchy.  However, Swing is single threaded and nearly all Swing constructors and methods *must* be run in the AWT event dispatch thread.  Failing to do so results in unpredictable behavior.  Try changing your main method’s body to `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new App().initialize());`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just by adding the panel it isn't automatically rendered, you have to tell swing to actually render it. You can do that by either manually calling `frame.repaint()` or you can add the panel before calling `frame.setVisible(true)` since this is already rendering the components on the frame.

Comment: I changed the order and put `JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src\\windows_default_wallpaper.png"));
        desktopFrame.add(background);` above everything else